# How can I get these NPCs to appear again?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I seem to have a bug where various quest NPCs have disappeared from the city they are supposed to be in. For example, if I look on the map for Maven Black-Briar (because I have a quest leading to her), it says she's directly in the middle of Riften. If I follow my compass though, it leads me out of the city and tries to make me jump over the city walls or something to get to her. This also happened to me with Carlotta in Whiterun. How can I begin trying to resolve this bug?

e: I'm playing on the PC and I have all the DLC.

Comment: What platform is this on?  For PC this is a fairly simple fix.

Comment: I'm playing on the PC, sorry. Added that to my OP.

Comment: Open up the console by pressing `~`.  `player.placeatme <BaseID> <#>` is one command you can use.  `<BaseID>` should be replaced with the NPC's base ID ([which you can find here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29/Characters#Characters)) and the `<#>` is how many you want, so 1 should suffice.

Comment: @DavidStarkey A heads-up on the `placeatme` console command: Using that command will instantly summon an instance (a copy) of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for named objects or NPCs. That command creates a new copy of an object/actor in the world; using it with named objects/NPCs can result in duplicates, which could cause glitches and other unwanted game behavior. [Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/123856/4797).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try teleporting the missing NPC to your location through console commands.

Console commands to teleport the missing NPC to the player's current location:
`prid <RefID>`
`moveto player`

`prid` targets an entity. [Maven Black-Briar](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Maven_Black-Briar)'s refID is 19DD1. [Carlotta Valentia](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Carlotta_Valentia)'s refID is 1A675.

(*Another method to target instead of using `prid <refID>` is to open up the console and then click on an entity, this will automatically do `prid <RefID>` for the clicked entity. However, this method won't be useful in your situation as the follower is not near your vicinity, and can't be clicked on.*)

`moveto player` moves that targeted entity near the vicinity of the player.

The missing NPC should now be near you after doing this.  If for some weird reason, he/she is dead (could happen with Carlotta, but not with Maven, an essential NPC), use the console command `resurrect 1`. The missing NPC should go back to life.

If for another weird reason, the missing NPC is still not near your vicinity after doing this, he/she may have been 'disabled' from the game, making him/her not appear in the game. Type `enable` in the console to remedy this. If he/she appears but is already dead, type `resurrect 1`.

More info on console commands here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console